# Alfresco bean not recognized

Tags: javascript, alfresco, spring-bean

I have configured new multi-select button in the document library:

[image]

When the button is clicked it should execute javascript function onActionAddToList which later calls bean function insert. Everything works except the bean function - it is not called/recognized. Am I doing something wrong? I am wondering if I should configure bean in an other place? I'm using Alfresco 5.2.0 SDK 3.0.1 Below you can find corresponding code:

```
<!--  /alfresco/web-extension/site-data/extensions/my-extension.xml  in share-jar -->

<configurations>
  <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
    <multi-select>
      <action type="action-link" id="onActionAddToList" icon="document-approve" label="Add item to a list" />
    </multi-select>
  </config>
  <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocLibCustom" replace="true">
    <dependencies>
      <js src="/components/documentlibrary/custom-documentlibrary-actions.js" />
    </dependencies>
  </config>
</configurations>


<!--  resources/components/documentlibrary/custom-documentlibrary-actions.js in share-jar

YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("registerAction", {
  actionName: "onActionAddToList",
  fn: function custom_onActionAddToList(record)
  {
     Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({ title: "Info", text: listManagement.insert("Hello")});
  }
});

<!-- alfresco/module/project/context/service-context.xml in platform-jar -->

<beans>
  <bean id="com.test.actions.ListManagement" class="com.test.actions.ListManagement"       parent="baseJavaScriptExtension">
    <property name="extensionName" value="listManagement"/>
  </bean>
</beans>

<!-- java/com/test/actions/ListManagement.java in platform-jar -->

public class ListManagement extends BaseProcessorExtension {
  public String insert(String text) {
    return text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [question](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/234699-bean-is-not-recognized) and refer this [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-action-doclib.html) to call javabacked actions.